# Add a JSON layer in a Button click - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependencies

I am new in `Xamarin.Forms` and I want to add a JSON layer in a button click in my map. How can I do this?

I  am using using `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` for creating map.

I have tried with a dependency for adding JSON layer.I found a solution for android ,but i am stuck on ios

Here is my code:

```
private void Close_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var _IIGeoJsonLayer = DependencyService.Get<IGeoJsonLayer>();
        _IIGeoJsonLayer.AddLayerJson();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is my Dependency Service:

```
public void AddLayerJson()
{
    GoogleMap gmap =null;
    GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(gmap, Resource.Raw.jsonFile, Android.App.Application.Context);
    layer.AddLayerToMap();
}
```

Comment: You do not have reference the "on-screen" GoogleMap instance, why not add a method to a custom map renderer subclass

Comment: @SushiHangover  Actually I want to add the geojson layer in to the map in a button click when i add the code in renderer , it execute the first time the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomRenderer.CS

```
  protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map); 
         gmap = map;
        KMLClass _class = new KMLClass(gmap);
    }
```

Class.cs

```
  public class KMLClass
  {
  public static  GoogleMap gmap;

    public KMLClass(GoogleMap map)
    {
        if(gmap==null)
        {
            if(map!=null)
            {
                gmap = map;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddKML()
    {
        GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(gmap, Resource.Raw.jsonFile, Android.App.Application.Context);
        layer.AddLayerToMap();
    }
```

Dependency Class

```
 public class JsonLayerAdd : IGeoJsonLayer
{
    GoogleMap map = null;
    public void AddLayerJson()
    {
        KMLClass _map = new KMLClass(map);
        _map.AddKML();
    }
}
```